# Can I access other days for On This Day?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

As of today, Facebook's "On This Day" allows users to see memories from only the current day. How about seeing memories from other days?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Per [this post in the Facebook Help community](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10153555237120498) from a verified Facebook Help Team member, this feature is not available.

> Is there a "on this day" archives you can search for previous posts you have made? I can only view todays "one this day" provided in my notifications and can not search previous "on this day" that have been previously provided.
>
> ---
>
> Thanks for your question! Unfortunately, the functionality you are requesting is not currently available. We will keep your suggestion in mind as we continue to improve Facebook.

It is then suggested that if this is a feature that you want, you should use the [Facebook Feedback form](https://www.facebook.com/help/127103474099499/?ref=u2u)

Answer (score 1):

If you know what day it was you can just search back on that day/the day either side of it, and check every year until you find it. I forgot to save something from yesterdays memories so I went on yesterdays date and checked my activity for 2019 2018 etc. till I found it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. If, on your phone app, you click the 3dots labeled "More" --> then Activity Log --> at the top you can select a specific year, month, day to view your timeline.

Comment: While this might be a viable workaround, on Web Applications we prefer that solutions be, well, Web Applications. Not everyone has a smartphone or uses the Facebook app on it if they do.

Comment: @ale ah, this Activity log is in all, also web. Answerer wrote bad that only in app, but it needs to be fixed cuz it is actually in web and in both apps.

Comment: The fact that this Answer is not for the "Web" interface is not nearly as problematic as the fact, that it doesn't actually answer the OP's Question.  The OP is asking how to "see *memories*" from a different day (of year).  The "Memories" option is provided by FB to allow someone to *re*-Post a prior Post (albeit currently from only the same day of year) they've made on their timeline as a *new* Post as a "Memory".  Just searching and opening a prior Post does not give you *that* option, such that you'd have to wait another *year* if you forgot / didn't have time to Share as a Memory.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah you can, just not directly.

If you wrote the memory personally, click search and type your name and some of the words from the post if you remember them. It should come up.

This is yesterday's memory, I found it by typing in what I remembered from it.[image]

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the OP's Question.  The OP is asking how to "see *memories*" from a different day (of year).  The "Memories" option is provided by FB to allow someone to *re*-Post a prior Post (albeit currently from only the same day of year) they've made on their timeline as a *new* Post *as - a - "Memory"*.  Just searching for and opening a prior Post does not give you *that* option, such that you'd have to wait another *year* if you forgot / didn't have time to Share as a Memory.  Critical design shortfall on FB's part.